# Python UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2014' in position 15: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('http://habrahabr.ru/')
q = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h1[@class='title']/a[@class='post_title']")
driver.close()

for w in q:
    print(w.text)
```

Fails only for some specific characters. Adding .encode('utf-8') helps from fail but makes the output look like this: b'\xd0\xa7\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0. Converting w.text to string doesn't help either.
Would really appreciate the explanation and solution!
Thanks!

Comment: Ignoring an issue with closing driver before reading elements everything works just fine for me, both on Python  2.7.9 and 3.4.2. Could you provide more details? OS, Python version, terminal locale...

Comment: Sorry for that. Windows 8.1, Python 3.4, cp866.

Comment: what webpage are you scraping? Decoding as utf-8 if it is not utf-8 encoded is not going to give you correct output

Comment: How do I get to know their encode method?